# Cannot connect usb 3.0 to vm workstation 10

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I'm having problem with connecting usb 3.0 to vm workstation 10. The host is window 7

x64. I try installing intel ext usb 3.0 but didn't work.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions, not general software problems.